# what is node name of element without any html tag?

Tags: c#, html, linq, html-agility-pack

I want to remove the text which has no html tag from html document. i am using LINQ.

```
 doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(d => d.Name == "script" 
                                        || d.Name == "style" 
                                        || d.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Comment)
                               .ToList()
                               .ForEach(d => d.Remove());
```

i am using this piece of code. and i want to add one more condition in LINQ, so i can remove any text which has no tag.

```
<div>hello</div>hello world
```

and in result, i just want "hello". right now i am getting "hellohello world".

Please help me to resolve this issue. 
is there any way to remove this text by using LINQ command? i have an idea that if i know the name of descendant which has no tag, then i can solve it by simply adding one more condition.

Comment: What you want to do with this `ForEach(d => d.Remove())`?? Since `ForEach` doesn't return anything this won't compile if you try to assign it to a variable.

Comment: i am removing all nodes of script, style and comment tags by this. this code is working fine. i have tested it on multiple documents. now i just want to remove "text which has no tags" as asked in question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this to remove any non-tagged text:

```
    doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
        .Where(d => d.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text && d.ParentNode.Equals(doc.DocumentNode))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(d => d.Remove());
```